# ubuntu - apache - virtual host doesn't process mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04, apache2

I have an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu and Apache installed on.

The traffic to this instance is always through port 80, since it has a load balancer in front of it who process the https request.

I want to make sure that even if someone try to browse it through regular http, it will automatically be redirected to the same url as https.

**This is my .htaccess:**

```
Options -Indexes

#Set the response headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Enable the Rewrite Engine
    RewriteEngine On

    #Redirect to the Https site always.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


</IfModule>
```

**this is the virtual host config file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin admin@my_domain.com

    ServerName dev_brands.my_domain.com

    ServerAlias new_dev_brands.my_domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev_brands.my_domain.com/public_html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/dev_brands.my_domain.com>
       AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I know the ..htaccess file if being processed since if I just type in random text - it cause 500 error.

Even when I try to redirect traffic just to Google - it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite installed and enabled?

Comment: I do see it rewrite.load in my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

Comment: What happens when you run `a2enmod rewrite` and restart Apache?

Comment: @CraigWatsonits say the mode rewrite is already enabled

Comment: Use LogLevel to log all of the actions mod_rewrite takes (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html). The logs will tell you every step that is taken, and why a rule matched or didn't match.